# XPATH Select child elements whose type's element name is xs:simpleType

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to select all child elements in the sequence whose implemented type's element name is of xs:simpleType.

```
<xs:complexType name="Truck">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Car">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DriverName" type="Name">
                    ...
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Engine" type="TruckEngine">
                    ...                   
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Where the type "Name" looks like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Name">
    ...
</xs:simpleType>
```

and "TruckEngine" looks like:

```
<xs:complexType name="TruckEngine">
    ... 
</xs:complexType>
```

How would I create an XPATH to select the element DriverName? So far I have something like xs:complexType/xs:complexContent/xs:extension/xs:sequence/xs:element, but I don't know how improve my selection any further. I have had a really difficult time searching for relevant information as I am not sure what terminology to use to select something like this. I have modified my example to be something more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
//xs:element[@type = //xs:simpleType/@name]
```

although I'd recommend a more explicit path instead of using `//`.

(Edit: Changed `eq` to `=`)

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet, but you pushed us in the right direction.  I modified it to be: xs:element[contains(@type, //xs:simpleType/@name)]

Comment: I forgot to say, that the reason for using contains was because the //xs:simpleType was catching all simpleTypes under the root of the document, so a direct comparison can't be done.  Contains searched through the list of matched elements and then compared their names against our element's type.

Comment: @kurtzbot - Did you try `=` instead of `eq`? (I made an edit for more than one `xs:simpleType`) Glad you got it working though.

Comment: yea, I figured you had meant the actual '=' symbol and tried that first, it did not work.  I had to use contains.

Comment: Please see my criticism of this answer. It only works under very limited circumstances, though it may be OK for this use case.

Comment: Upvoted because it was a good example to understand `XPath`'s syntax, which I am new to and find easier to understand via example than via reading the spec.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to extract information from a schema document is difficult (almost impossible) unless you know the conventions used by the schema author. For example, the solution from DevNull (which you accepted) will only work if the type is defined in the same schema document, it will only work for a named (not anonymous) type, and it will only work for schema documents with no targetNamespace.

For a more general solution, that works with any schema regardless of authoring convention, don't try to do it this way: use a schema API that gives you access to the "cooked" schema components following analysis by a schema processor. One approach is to use Xerces which offers a Java API to schema components, another is to use Saxon's SCM format which provides an XML representation of the "cooked" schema components in a single document.